# Error in SetData() in magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to update a custom field of customer_entity in magento I am using the following code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

     print_r($customer->getData());
     try {   
                     $customer->setData('field', $flag);
         $insertId = $customer->save()->getId();
             echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
                      print_r($customer->getData());
        } catch (Exception $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
```

Now I does not get why it is not saving in a database, when i write the log customer data has the updated value, but when i try to  see in the database it is not reflecting.

Any Idea?

Edited:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
        $sql = "update `customer_entity` set `field` = ".$flag." where`entity_id` =".$customerId;
        $write->query($sql);
```

This code is working with charm but the above code nention at the top does work.
Does any body have any idea?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you noticed that setData() does work with the default magento database fields. For eg, i've added 2 fields to the 'customer_entity' table. I can insert into all the other fields using ORM but not the two fields that I created. I've to use SQL for those. :(

Comment: Did you solve your issue, i am having same problem, and i can't change from innoDB to MyISAM because of foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache once and reindexing from magento admin! Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

first check the following
1. check you made the database table defined in the config.xml in the resource model.
2.get the value for $flag and check whether the field is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:- Check your resource table name in config.xml file,and Clear your cache folder inside /var folder and than check.

Step2:- If step 1 is not working than reindex your project and than check.

Step3:- If step 1 and 2 is not working, than check your table Engine type if it's InnoDB than change it to MyISAM and than check.

For more Info [click here](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/error-in-setdata-in-magento.html)